# How to use Queues in Laravel Project Code without Artisan commands?

Tags: laravel, queue

I am learning Queues in Laravel I want a practical learning I didnt get exactly what i want still. Please anyone explain me about this.

Answer (score 0):

You should take reference from below URL.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/why-laravel-queues-are-awesome